# java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityMain] Unity 4.3.4 + Nexus 5

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, unity-game-engine

I made an application in free Unity 4.3.4. The application works perfectly on Android and iOS. But the Nexus 4 devices and 5 is giving problems. I get the following stack.

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityMain]
Unity version : 4.3.4f1
Device model : LGE Nexus 5
Device fingerprint: google/hammerhead/hammerhead:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys

Caused by: java.lang.Error: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (?), fault addr --------
Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
pid: 24580, tid: 24580, name: .corsegames.wcp >>> com.corsegames.wcp <<<
r0 00000000 r1 00006004 r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 00000006 r5 00000001 r6 00006004 r7 0000010c
r8 00000000 r9 bee47680 sl bee47678 fp 000005d7
ip 416eecac sp bee475e8 lr 400bffe5 pc 400cef90 cpsr 00000006

at libc.tgkill(tgkill:12)
at libc.pthread_kill(pthread_kill:48)
at libc.raise(raise:10)
at libc.00011f2b(Native Method)
at libc.abort(abort:4)
at libart.art::Runtime::Abort()(Runtime:168)
at libart.art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()(LogMessage:506)
at libart.0004aa5d(Native Method)
at libart.art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)(JniAbortF:52)
at libart.00147bfb(Native Method)
at libunity.003d3bac(Native Method)
at Unknown.0000decc(Unknown Source)
at AndroidJNI.GetArrayLength(Native Method)
at AndroidJNISafe.GetArrayLength(<0x0001c>:28)
at _AndroidJNIHelper.InvokeJavaProxyMethod(<0x0002b>:43)
at <Module>.runtime_invoke_intptr_object_intptr_intptr(Native Method)
at libmono.000238cb(Native Method)
at libmono.mono_runtime_invoke(mono_runtime_invoke:144)
at libunity.002a0030(Native Method)
at libunity.002a011c(Native Method)
at libunity.002a0198(Native Method)
at libunity.003a5e80(Native Method)
at data@app@com.00605f84(Native Method)
```

I found no line of my code, Unity is all internal. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Anything else of interest in the logcat? Did you try updating your Unity version to the latest 4.5?

Comment: No, I heard out there that is a bug Ngui. But I'm not sure. I will download 4.5, but do not think that's the soución. thank you very much

Comment: Given that there is no mention of NGUI in that stack trace, I'm hard pressed to believe NGUI is involved there in any way. In fact, crashes like that with NGUI are very unlikely. Try updating and see if that fixes your problem. There were numerous fixes for 4.5 and some of those might well be addressing the issues you see.

Comment: Thanks to all. I solve the problem! I update to Unity 4.5.1 and upgrade java to 1.7u60.